# How to check element is not null in java

Tags: java

```
filterItems = null;
filterItems = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();


Iterator<String> it = RefListMap.keySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String s = (String) it.next();
            filterItems.add(new SelectItem(s, s));
        }
```

Now i am getting filterItems size=1 but that value is null.How to check array element is not equal to null.

```
if(filterItems != null)
{

 code
}
```

but this condition is not working...Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
String s = (String) it.next();
if(s != null){
    filterItems.add(new SelectItem(s, s));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Presumably the value you're getting from the `RefListMap` is null. You might check whether `s` was null before you add it to `filterItems`.